# Django Model Formset Only first form required

Tags: django, django-forms

In a modelformset with 3 copies of the form, how do i specify that only the first set is required but the rest can be blank or null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subclass `BaseModelFormSet` so it modifies the first form and makes it required:

```
from django.forms.models import BaseModelFormSet

class OneRequiredFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def _construct_form(self, i, **kwargs):
        f = super(OneRequiredFormSet, self)._construct_form(i, **kwargs)
        if i == 0:
            f.empty_permitted = False
            f.required = True
        return f
```

Then you can use the `formset` keyword argument to tell `modelformset_factory` to use your new class:

```
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory

ParticipantFormSet = modelformset_factory(Participant, extra=1,
                                          form=ParticipantForm,
                                          formset=OneRequiredFormSet)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used something like this for inline formsets:

```
class BaseSomethingFormset(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseSomethingFormset, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.forms[0].empty_permitted = False
        self.forms[0].required = True
```

The form fields must be by default set to `required=False`

Answer (score 1):

Matthew Flanagan has a [package of things for Django](http://wadofstuff.blogspot.com/2009/08/requiring-at-least-one-inline-formset.html), and in that package is the RequireOneFormset class. You can easily extend this class to require 3 forms instead of one.

Hope that helps you out.